# Cannot mv file into a subdirectory of itself

Tags: 20.04, files, filesystem, directory, mv

I was trying to rename a file in `/media/user/TOSHIBA EXT/Fotos/Chronologisch` using `mv`, and I get the following error:

```sh
/media/user/TOSHIBA EXT/Fotos/Chronologisch$ mv "DSC00001.JPG" "12.10.2021-16:20:56.jpg"
mv: moving 'DSC00001.JPG' into a subdirectory of itself ('12.10.2021-16:20:56.jpg') is not possible
```

The contents of the folder are ~3000 photos:

```sh
/media/frederic/TOSHIBA EXT/Fotos/Chronologisch$ ls -a
.             DSC04106.JPG  DSC04539.JPG  DSC04942.JPG  DSC08209.JPG  DSC08594.JPG  DSC08994.JPG  DSC09426.JPG  DSC09791.JPG
..            DSC04107.JPG  DSC04540.JPG  DSC04943.JPG  DSC08210.JPG  DSC08596.JPG  DSC08995.JPG  DSC09427.JPG  DSC09792.JPG
DSC00001.JPG  DSC04111.JPG  DSC04541.JPG  DSC04944.JPG  DSC08211.JPG  DSC08597.JPG  DSC08996.JPG  DSC09428.JPG  DSC09793.JPG
DSC00002.JPG  DSC04112.JPG  DSC04542.JPG  DSC04946.JPG  DSC08212.JPG  DSC08598.JPG  DSC08997.JPG  DSC09429.JPG  DSC09794.JPG
DSC00003.JPG  DSC04113.JPG  DSC04543.JPG  DSC04949.JPG  DSC08213.JPG  DSC08599.JPG  DSC08998.JPG  DSC09430.JPG  DSC09795.JPG
DSC00004.JPG  DSC04114.JPG  DSC04544.JPG  DSC04950.JPG  DSC08214.JPG  DSC08600.JPG  DSC08999.JPG  DSC09431.JPG  DSC09796.JPG
DSC00005.JPG  DSC04115.JPG  DSC04545.JPG  DSC04951.JPG  DSC08215.JPG  DSC08601.JPG  DSC09000.JPG  DSC09433.JPG  DSC09797.JPG
DSC00006.JPG  DSC04116.JPG  DSC04546.JPG  DSC04952.JPG  DSC08216.JPG  DSC08602.JPG  DSC09001.JPG  DSC09434.JPG  DSC09798.JPG
DSC00007.JPG  DSC04117.JPG  DSC04547.JPG  DSC04953.JPG  DSC08217.JPG  DSC08603.JPG  DSC09002.JPG  DSC09435.JPG  DSC09799.JPG
DSC00008.JPG  DSC04118.JPG  DSC04548.JPG  DSC04954.JPG  DSC08218.JPG  DSC08604.JPG  DSC09003.JPG  DSC09436.JPG  DSC09801.JPG
DSC00190.JPG  DSC04324.JPG  DSC04761.JPG  DSC07998.JPG  DSC08425.JPG  DSC08808.JPG  DSC09234.JPG  DSC09620.JPG  DSC09989.JPG
DSC00191.JPG  DSC04325.JPG  DSC04762.JPG  DSC07999.JPG  DSC08426.JPG  DSC08809.JPG  DSC09235.JPG  DSC09621.JPG  DSC09990.JPG
DSC00192.JPG  DSC04326.JPG  DSC04763.JPG  DSC08009.JPG  DSC08427.JPG  DSC08810.JPG  DSC09236.JPG  DSC09622.JPG  DSC09991.JPG
DSC00193.JPG  DSC04327.JPG  DSC04764.JPG  DSC08010.JPG  DSC08428.JPG  DSC08811.JPG  DSC09237.JPG  DSC09623.JPG  DSC09992.JPG
DSC00194.JPG  DSC04328.JPG  DSC04765.JPG  DSC08011.JPG  DSC08429.JPG  DSC08812.JPG  DSC09238.JPG  DSC09624.JPG  DSC09993.JPG
DSC00195.JPG  DSC04329.JPG  DSC04766.JPG  DSC08017.JPG  DSC08430.JPG  DSC08813.JPG  DSC09239.JPG  DSC09625.JPG  DSC09994.JPG
DSC00196.JPG  DSC04330.JPG  DSC04767.JPG  DSC08019.JPG  DSC08431.JPG  DSC08814.JPG  DSC09240.JPG  DSC09626.JPG  DSC09995.JPG
DSC00197.JPG  DSC04331.JPG  DSC04768.JPG  DSC08020.JPG  DSC08432.JPG  DSC08815.JPG  DSC09241.JPG  DSC09627.JPG  DSC09996.JPG
DSC00199.JPG  DSC04332.JPG  DSC04770.JPG  DSC08022.JPG  DSC08433.JPG  DSC08816.JPG  DSC09242.JPG  DSC09628.JPG  DSC09997.JPG
DSC00200.JPG  DSC04333.JPG  DSC04771.JPG  DSC08023.JPG  DSC08434.JPG  DSC08817.JPG  DSC09243.JPG  DSC09629.JPG  DSC09998.JPG
DSC00201.JPG  DSC04334.JPG  DSC04772.JPG  DSC08024.JPG  DSC08435.JPG  DSC08818.JPG  DSC09244.JPG  DSC09630.JPG  DSC09999.JPG
DSC00203.JPG  DSC04335.JPG  DSC04776.JPG  DSC08025.JPG  DSC08436.JPG  DSC08820.JPG  DSC09245.JPG  DSC09631.JPG  Flockenblume-1.JPG
DSC00204.JPG  DSC04336.JPG  DSC04777.JPG  DSC08026.JPG  DSC08437.JPG  DSC08828.JPG  DSC09246.JPG  DSC09632.JPG  Flockenblume-2.JPG
DSC00205.JPG  DSC04337.JPG  DSC04778.JPG  DSC08027.JPG  DSC08438.JPG  DSC08831.JPG  DSC09247.JPG  DSC09633.JPG  Flockenblume-3.JPG
DSC00206.JPG  DSC04340.JPG  DSC04779.JPG  DSC08028.JPG  DSC08439.JPG  DSC08832.JPG  DSC09249.JPG  DSC09634.JPG  Flockenblume-4.JPG
DSC00207.JPG  DSC04341.JPG  DSC04780.JPG  DSC08029.JPG  DSC08440.JPG  DSC08833.JPG  DSC09250.JPG  DSC09635.JPG  Flockenblume-5.JPG
DSC00208.JPG  DSC04351.JPG  DSC04781.JPG  DSC08030.JPG  DSC08441.JPG  DSC08834.JPG  DSC09252.JPG  DSC09636.JPG  Flockenblume-6.JPG
DSC00209.JPG  DSC04352.JPG  DSC04782.JPG  DSC08031.JPG  DSC08442.JPG  DSC08835.JPG  DSC09254.JPG  DSC09637.JPG  Flockenblume-7.JPG
DSC00210.JPG  DSC04354.JPG  DSC04783.JPG  DSC08032.JPG  DSC08443.JPG  DSC08836.JPG  DSC09255.JPG  DSC09638.JPG  Frederics-Lieblingsäpfel-1.JPG
DSC00211.JPG  DSC04357.JPG  DSC04784.JPG  DSC08034.JPG  DSC08444.JPG  DSC08837.JPG  DSC09257.JPG  DSC09639.JPG  Frederics-Lieblingsäpfel-2.JPG
DSC00212.JPG  DSC04358.JPG  DSC04785.JPG  DSC08035.JPG  DSC08445.JPG  DSC08838.JPG  DSC09261.JPG  DSC09640.JPG  Frederics-Lieblingsäpfel-3.jpg
DSC00213.JPG  DSC04359.JPG  DSC04786.JPG  DSC08036.JPG  DSC08446.JPG  DSC08839.JPG  DSC09262.JPG  DSC09641.JPG  Frederics-Lieblingsäpfel-4.jpg
DSC00214.JPG  DSC04364.JPG  DSC04787.JPG  DSC08037.JPG  DSC08447.JPG  DSC08840.JPG  DSC09263.JPG  DSC09642.JPG  Krähe-in-Kirschbaum-1.JPG
DSC00215.JPG  DSC04365.JPG  DSC04788.JPG  DSC08038.JPG  DSC08448.JPG  DSC08841.JPG  DSC09266.JPG  DSC09643.JPG  Krähe-in-Kirschbaum-2.JPG
DSC00216.JPG  DSC04366.JPG  DSC04789.JPG  DSC08039.JPG  DSC08449.JPG  DSC08842.JPG  DSC09267.JPG  DSC09644.JPG  Krähe-in-Kirschbaum-3.JPG
DSC00217.JPG  DSC04367.JPG  DSC04790.JPG  DSC08040.JPG  DSC08450.JPG  DSC08843.JPG  DSC09268.JPG  DSC09645.JPG  Kürbisblüten-14.07.21-1.JPG
DSC00219.JPG  DSC04368.JPG  DSC04791.JPG  DSC08042.JPG  DSC08451.JPG  DSC08844.JPG  DSC09270.JPG  DSC09646.JPG  Kürbisblüten-14.07.21-2.JPG
DSC00220.JPG  DSC04369.JPG  DSC04792.JPG  DSC08046.JPG  DSC08452.JPG  DSC08845.JPG  DSC09272.JPG  DSC09647.JPG  Kürbisblüten-14.07.21-3.JPG
DSC00221.JPG  DSC04370.JPG  DSC04793.JPG  DSC08047.JPG  DSC08453.JPG  DSC08846.JPG  DSC09273.JPG  DSC09648.JPG  Kürbisblüten-19.07.21-1.JPG
DSC00222.JPG  DSC04371.JPG  DSC04794.JPG  DSC08048.JPG  DSC08454.JPG  DSC08847.JPG  DSC09274.JPG  DSC09649.JPG  Kürbisblüten-19.07.21-2.JPG
DSC00223.JPG  DSC04372.JPG  DSC04795.JPG  DSC08049.JPG  DSC08455.JPG  DSC08848.JPG  DSC09275.JPG  DSC09651.JPG  Kürbisblüten-19.07.21-3.JPG
DSC00224.JPG  DSC04373.JPG  DSC04796.JPG  DSC08050.JPG  DSC08456.JPG  DSC08849.JPG  DSC09276.JPG  DSC09653.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-1.JPG
DSC00225.JPG  DSC04375.JPG  DSC04797.JPG  DSC08051.JPG  DSC08457.JPG  DSC08850.JPG  DSC09277.JPG  DSC09654.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-2.JPG
DSC00226.JPG  DSC04376.JPG  DSC04798.JPG  DSC08052.JPG  DSC08458.JPG  DSC08851.JPG  DSC09278.JPG  DSC09655.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-3.JPG
DSC00227.JPG  DSC04377.JPG  DSC04799.JPG  DSC08053.JPG  DSC08459.JPG  DSC08853.JPG  DSC09279.JPG  DSC09656.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-4.JPG
DSC00228.JPG  DSC04379.JPG  DSC04801.JPG  DSC08054.JPG  DSC08460.JPG  DSC08854.JPG  DSC09280.JPG  DSC09657.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-5.JPG
DSC00229.JPG  DSC04380.JPG  DSC04802.JPG  DSC08055.JPG  DSC08461.JPG  DSC08856.JPG  DSC09281.JPG  DSC09658.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-6.JPG
DSC00230.JPG  DSC04381.JPG  DSC04806.JPG  DSC08057.JPG  DSC08462.JPG  DSC08857.JPG  DSC09282.JPG  DSC09659.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-7.JPG
DSC00231.JPG  DSC04382.JPG  DSC04807.JPG  DSC08058.JPG  DSC08463.JPG  DSC08858.JPG  DSC09285.JPG  DSC09660.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-8.JPG
DSC00232.JPG  DSC04383.JPG  DSC04808.JPG  DSC08059.JPG  DSC08464.JPG  DSC08859.JPG  DSC09288.JPG  DSC09661.JPG  Lecker-Birnensorte-9.JPG
DSC00233.JPG  DSC04385.JPG  DSC04809.JPG  DSC08060.JPG  DSC08465.JPG  DSC08860.JPG  DSC09291.JPG  DSC09662.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-1.JPG
DSC00234.JPG  DSC04386.JPG  DSC04810.JPG  DSC08061.JPG  DSC08466.JPG  DSC08861.JPG  DSC09293.JPG  DSC09663.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-2.JPG
DSC00235.JPG  DSC04387.JPG  DSC04812.JPG  DSC08062.JPG  DSC08467.JPG  DSC08866.JPG  DSC09294.JPG  DSC09664.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-3.JPG
DSC00236.JPG  DSC04388.JPG  DSC04813.JPG  DSC08063.JPG  DSC08468.JPG  DSC08867.JPG  DSC09295.JPG  DSC09665.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-4.JPG
DSC00237.JPG  DSC04389.JPG  DSC04814.JPG  DSC08064.JPG  DSC08469.JPG  DSC08868.JPG  DSC09296.JPG  DSC09666.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-5.JPG
DSC00238.JPG  DSC04390.JPG  DSC04816.JPG  DSC08065.JPG  DSC08470.JPG  DSC08869.JPG  DSC09297.JPG  DSC09667.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-6.JPG
DSC00239.JPG  DSC04391.JPG  DSC04817.JPG  DSC08066.JPG  DSC08471.JPG  DSC08871.JPG  DSC09298.JPG  DSC09668.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-7.JPG
DSC00240.JPG  DSC04392.JPG  DSC04820.JPG  DSC08067.JPG  DSC08472.JPG  DSC08872.JPG  DSC09299.JPG  DSC09669.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Kapuzinerkresseblatt-8.JPG
DSC00241.JPG  DSC04393.JPG  DSC04821.JPG  DSC08069.JPG  DSC08473.JPG  DSC08873.JPG  DSC09300.JPG  DSC09670.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-10.JPG
DSC00242.JPG  DSC04394.JPG  DSC04825.JPG  DSC08070.JPG  DSC08474.JPG  DSC08875.JPG  DSC09301.JPG  DSC09671.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-11.JPG
DSC00243.JPG  DSC04395.JPG  DSC04826.JPG  DSC08071.JPG  DSC08475.JPG  DSC08879.JPG  DSC09302.JPG  DSC09672.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-12.JPG
DSC00244.JPG  DSC04398.JPG  DSC04827.JPG  DSC08073.JPG  DSC08476.JPG  DSC08880.JPG  DSC09303.JPG  DSC09673.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-13.JPG
DSC00245.JPG  DSC04399.JPG  DSC04828.JPG  DSC08074.JPG  DSC08477.JPG  DSC08881.JPG  DSC09304.JPG  DSC09674.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-14.JPG
DSC00246.JPG  DSC04400.JPG  DSC04829.JPG  DSC08075.JPG  DSC08478.JPG  DSC08882.JPG  DSC09305.JPG  DSC09676.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-15.JPG
DSC00247.JPG  DSC04401.JPG  DSC04830.JPG  DSC08077.JPG  DSC08480.JPG  DSC08883.JPG  DSC09306.JPG  DSC09677.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-16.JPG
DSC00248.JPG  DSC04402.JPG  DSC04831.JPG  DSC08078.JPG  DSC08481.JPG  DSC08884.JPG  DSC09307.JPG  DSC09678.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-17.JPG
DSC00249.JPG  DSC04403.JPG  DSC04832.JPG  DSC08079.JPG  DSC08485.JPG  DSC08885.JPG  DSC09308.JPG  DSC09679.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-18.JPG
DSC00250.JPG  DSC04404.JPG  DSC04833.JPG  DSC08080.JPG  DSC08486.JPG  DSC08886.JPG  DSC09309.JPG  DSC09680.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-1.JPG
DSC00251.JPG  DSC04405.JPG  DSC04834.JPG  DSC08082.JPG  DSC08487.JPG  DSC08887.JPG  DSC09310.JPG  DSC09681.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-2.JPG
DSC00252.JPG  DSC04406.JPG  DSC04835.JPG  DSC08085.JPG  DSC08488.JPG  DSC08888.JPG  DSC09311.JPG  DSC09682.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-3.JPG
DSC00253.JPG  DSC04407.JPG  DSC04836.JPG  DSC08086.JPG  DSC08489.JPG  DSC08889.JPG  DSC09312.JPG  DSC09683.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-4.JPG
DSC00254.JPG  DSC04419.JPG  DSC04837.JPG  DSC08087.JPG  DSC08490.JPG  DSC08890.JPG  DSC09313.JPG  DSC09684.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-5.JPG
DSC00255.JPG  DSC04420.JPG  DSC04838.JPG  DSC08088.JPG  DSC08491.JPG  DSC08891.JPG  DSC09314.JPG  DSC09688.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-6.JPG
DSC00256.JPG  DSC04421.JPG  DSC04839.JPG  DSC08089.JPG  DSC08492.JPG  DSC08892.JPG  DSC09315.JPG  DSC09690.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-7.JPG
DSC00257.JPG  DSC04422.JPG  DSC04840.JPG  DSC08090.JPG  DSC08493.JPG  DSC08894.JPG  DSC09316.JPG  DSC09691.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-8.JPG
DSC00258.JPG  DSC04423.JPG  DSC04842.JPG  DSC08091.JPG  DSC08494.JPG  DSC08895.JPG  DSC09317.JPG  DSC09692.JPG  Mini-hält-Riesen-Löwenzahnblatt-9.JPG
DSC00259.JPG  DSC04425.JPG  DSC04843.JPG  DSC08092.JPG  DSC08495.JPG  DSC08896.JPG  DSC09318.JPG  DSC09693.JPG  Propellerflugzeug.JPG
DSC00260.JPG  DSC04426.JPG  DSC04845.JPG  DSC08093.JPG  DSC08496.JPG  DSC08897.JPG  DSC09319.JPG  DSC09694.JPG  rename_photos.py
DSC00261.JPG  DSC04427.JPG  DSC04846.JPG  DSC08094.JPG  DSC08497.JPG  DSC08898.JPG  DSC09320.JPG  DSC09695.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-1.JPG
DSC00262.JPG  DSC04428.JPG  DSC04847.JPG  DSC08095.JPG  DSC08498.JPG  DSC08899.JPG  DSC09321.JPG  DSC09696.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-2.JPG
DSC00263.JPG  DSC04429.JPG  DSC04848.JPG  DSC08096.JPG  DSC08499.JPG  DSC08900.JPG  DSC09322.JPG  DSC09697.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-3.JPG
DSC00264.JPG  DSC04430.JPG  DSC04849.JPG  DSC08097.JPG  DSC08500.JPG  DSC08901.JPG  DSC09323.JPG  DSC09698.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-4.JPG
DSC00265.JPG  DSC04431.JPG  DSC04850.JPG  DSC08098.JPG  DSC08501.JPG  DSC08902.JPG  DSC09324.JPG  DSC09699.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-5.JPG
DSC03395.JPG  DSC04432.JPG  DSC04851.JPG  DSC08099.JPG  DSC08502.JPG  DSC08904.JPG  DSC09327.JPG  DSC09700.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-6.JPG
DSC03396.JPG  DSC04433.JPG  DSC04852.JPG  DSC08100.JPG  DSC08503.JPG  DSC08905.JPG  DSC09328.JPG  DSC09701.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-7.JPG
DSC03397.JPG  DSC04434.JPG  DSC04853.JPG  DSC08101.JPG  DSC08504.JPG  DSC08906.JPG  DSC09330.JPG  DSC09702.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-8.JPG
DSC03399.JPG  DSC04435.JPG  DSC04854.JPG  DSC08102.JPG  DSC08505.JPG  DSC08907.JPG  DSC09332.JPG  DSC09703.JPG  Rotkohl-Rosette-9.JPG
DSC03405.JPG  DSC04436.JPG  DSC04855.JPG  DSC08103.JPG  DSC08507.JPG  DSC08908.JPG  DSC09333.JPG  DSC09704.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-10.JPG
DSC03406.JPG  DSC04437.JPG  DSC04856.JPG  DSC08104.JPG  DSC08508.JPG  DSC08909.JPG  DSC09334.JPG  DSC09706.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-11.JPG
DSC03407.JPG  DSC04438.JPG  DSC04857.JPG  DSC08105.JPG  DSC08509.JPG  DSC08910.JPG  DSC09339.JPG  DSC09707.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-12.JPG
DSC03408.JPG  DSC04439.JPG  DSC04858.JPG  DSC08106.JPG  DSC08510.JPG  DSC08911.JPG  DSC09341.JPG  DSC09708.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-13.JPG
DSC03409.JPG  DSC04440.JPG  DSC04859.JPG  DSC08107.JPG  DSC08511.JPG  DSC08912.JPG  DSC09342.JPG  DSC09709.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-14.JPG
DSC03410.JPG  DSC04441.JPG  DSC04860.JPG  DSC08108.JPG  DSC08512.JPG  DSC08913.JPG  DSC09343.JPG  DSC09710.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-1.JPG
DSC03411.JPG  DSC04442.JPG  DSC04861.JPG  DSC08109.JPG  DSC08513.JPG  DSC08914.JPG  DSC09344.JPG  DSC09711.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-2.JPG
DSC03412.JPG  DSC04443.JPG  DSC04862.JPG  DSC08110.JPG  DSC08514.JPG  DSC08915.JPG  DSC09345.JPG  DSC09712.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-3.JPG
DSC03413.JPG  DSC04444.JPG  DSC04863.JPG  DSC08111.JPG  DSC08515.JPG  DSC08916.JPG  DSC09346.JPG  DSC09713.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-4.JPG
DSC03414.JPG  DSC04445.JPG  DSC04864.JPG  DSC08112.JPG  DSC08516.JPG  DSC08917.JPG  DSC09347.JPG  DSC09714.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-5.JPG
DSC03415.JPG  DSC04446.JPG  DSC04865.JPG  DSC08113.JPG  DSC08517.JPG  DSC08918.JPG  DSC09348.JPG  DSC09715.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-6.JPG
DSC03416.JPG  DSC04447.JPG  DSC04866.JPG  DSC08114.JPG  DSC08518.JPG  DSC08919.JPG  DSC09350.JPG  DSC09716.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-7.JPG
DSC03417.JPG  DSC04448.JPG  DSC04867.JPG  DSC08115.JPG  DSC08519.JPG  DSC08920.JPG  DSC09352.JPG  DSC09717.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-8.JPG
DSC03418.JPG  DSC04449.JPG  DSC04868.JPG  DSC08116.JPG  DSC08521.JPG  DSC08921.JPG  DSC09353.JPG  DSC09718.JPG  Schneebedeckte-Bäume-9.JPG
DSC03419.JPG  DSC04450.JPG  DSC04869.JPG  DSC08117.JPG  DSC08522.JPG  DSC08922.JPG  DSC09354.JPG  DSC09719.JPG  Schwarze-Johannisbeeren-Blitz.JPG
DSC03420.JPG  DSC04451.JPG  DSC04870.JPG  DSC08118.JPG  DSC08523.JPG  DSC08923.JPG  DSC09355.JPG  DSC09720.JPG  Schwarze-Johannissbeeren-1.JPG
DSC03426.JPG  DSC04452.JPG  DSC04871.JPG  DSC08119.JPG  DSC08524.JPG  DSC08924.JPG  DSC09360.JPG  DSC09721.JPG  Schwarze-Johannissbeeren-2.JPG
DSC03427.JPG  DSC04453.JPG  DSC04872.JPG  DSC08121.JPG  DSC08525.JPG  DSC08925.JPG  DSC09361.JPG  DSC09722.JPG  Schwarze-Johannissbeeren-3.JPG
DSC03428.JPG  DSC04454.JPG  DSC04876.JPG  DSC08122.JPG  DSC08526.JPG  DSC08926.JPG  DSC09362.JPG  DSC09723.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-10.JPG
DSC03429.JPG  DSC04455.JPG  DSC04877.JPG  DSC08123.JPG  DSC08527.JPG  DSC08928.JPG  DSC09363.JPG  DSC09724.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-11.JPG
DSC03430.JPG  DSC04456.JPG  DSC04878.JPG  DSC08125.JPG  DSC08528.JPG  DSC08929.JPG  DSC09364.JPG  DSC09725.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-1.JPG
DSC03431.JPG  DSC04457.JPG  DSC04879.JPG  DSC08126.JPG  DSC08529.JPG  DSC08930.JPG  DSC09365.JPG  DSC09726.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-2.JPG
DSC03433.JPG  DSC04458.JPG  DSC04880.JPG  DSC08127.JPG  DSC08530.JPG  DSC08931.JPG  DSC09366.JPG  DSC09727.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-3.JPG
DSC03434.JPG  DSC04459.JPG  DSC04881.JPG  DSC08128.JPG  DSC08531.JPG  DSC08932.JPG  DSC09368.JPG  DSC09728.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-4.JPG
DSC03435.JPG  DSC04460.JPG  DSC04882.JPG  DSC08129.JPG  DSC08532.JPG  DSC08933.JPG  DSC09369.JPG  DSC09729.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-5.JPG
DSC03436.JPG  DSC04461.JPG  DSC04883.JPG  DSC08130.JPG  DSC08533.JPG  DSC08934.JPG  DSC09370.JPG  DSC09734.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-6.JPG
DSC03437.JPG  DSC04462.JPG  DSC04884.JPG  DSC08145.JPG  DSC08534.JPG  DSC08935.JPG  DSC09371.JPG  DSC09735.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-7.JPG
DSC03438.JPG  DSC04463.JPG  DSC04885.JPG  DSC08146.JPG  DSC08535.JPG  DSC08936.JPG  DSC09372.JPG  DSC09736.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-8.JPG
DSC03439.JPG  DSC04464.JPG  DSC04886.JPG  DSC08147.JPG  DSC08536.JPG  DSC08939.JPG  DSC09373.JPG  DSC09737.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-9.JPG
DSC03440.JPG  DSC04465.JPG  DSC04887.JPG  DSC08149.JPG  DSC08537.JPG  DSC08940.JPG  DSC09374.JPG  DSC09738.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-10.JPG
DSC03442.JPG  DSC04466.JPG  DSC04888.JPG  DSC08150.JPG  DSC08539.JPG  DSC08941.JPG  DSC09375.JPG  DSC09739.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-11.JPG
DSC03444.JPG  DSC04467.JPG  DSC04889.JPG  DSC08152.JPG  DSC08540.JPG  DSC08942.JPG  DSC09376.JPG  DSC09740.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-12.JPG
DSC03445.JPG  DSC04468.JPG  DSC04890.JPG  DSC08153.JPG  DSC08541.JPG  DSC08945.JPG  DSC09377.JPG  DSC09741.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-13.JPG
DSC03446.JPG  DSC04469.JPG  DSC04891.JPG  DSC08154.JPG  DSC08542.JPG  DSC08946.JPG  DSC09378.JPG  DSC09742.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-14.JPG
DSC03447.JPG  DSC04470.JPG  DSC04892.JPG  DSC08157.JPG  DSC08546.JPG  DSC08947.JPG  DSC09379.JPG  DSC09743.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-15.JPG
DSC03448.JPG  DSC04471.JPG  DSC04893.JPG  DSC08158.JPG  DSC08548.JPG  DSC08948.JPG  DSC09380.JPG  DSC09744.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-1.JPG
DSC03454.JPG  DSC04473.JPG  DSC04894.JPG  DSC08159.JPG  DSC08549.JPG  DSC08949.JPG  DSC09381.JPG  DSC09745.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-2.JPG
DSC03455.JPG  DSC04474.JPG  DSC04895.JPG  DSC08160.JPG  DSC08550.JPG  DSC08950.JPG  DSC09382.JPG  DSC09746.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-3.JPG
DSC03456.JPG  DSC04476.JPG  DSC04896.JPG  DSC08161.JPG  DSC08551.JPG  DSC08951.JPG  DSC09383.JPG  DSC09747.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-4.JPG
DSC03457.JPG  DSC04481.JPG  DSC04897.JPG  DSC08162.JPG  DSC08552.JPG  DSC08952.JPG  DSC09384.JPG  DSC09748.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-5.JPG
DSC03458.JPG  DSC04486.JPG  DSC04898.JPG  DSC08163.JPG  DSC08553.JPG  DSC08953.JPG  DSC09385.JPG  DSC09749.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-6.JPG
DSC03459.JPG  DSC04487.JPG  DSC04899.JPG  DSC08164.JPG  DSC08554.JPG  DSC08954.JPG  DSC09386.JPG  DSC09750.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-7.JPG
DSC03460.JPG  DSC04488.JPG  DSC04900.JPG  DSC08165.JPG  DSC08555.JPG  DSC08955.JPG  DSC09387.JPG  DSC09751.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-8.JPG
DSC03461.JPG  DSC04489.JPG  DSC04901.JPG  DSC08166.JPG  DSC08556.JPG  DSC08956.JPG  DSC09388.JPG  DSC09752.JPG  Schwarzer-Käfer-auf-Tisch-9.JPG
DSC03464.JPG  DSC04495.JPG  DSC04902.JPG  DSC08167.JPG  DSC08557.JPG  DSC08957.JPG  DSC09389.JPG  DSC09753.JPG  Sich-paarende-Weinbergschnecken-1.JPG
DSC03466.JPG  DSC04496.JPG  DSC04903.JPG  DSC08168.JPG  DSC08558.JPG  DSC08958.JPG  DSC09390.JPG  DSC09754.JPG  Sich-paarende-Weinbergschnecken-3.JPG
DSC03467.JPG  DSC04500.JPG  DSC04904.JPG  DSC08169.JPG  DSC08559.JPG  DSC08959.JPG  DSC09391.JPG  DSC09755.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-10.JPG
DSC03468.JPG  DSC04501.JPG  DSC04905.JPG  DSC08171.JPG  DSC08560.JPG  DSC08960.JPG  DSC09392.JPG  DSC09756.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-11.JPG
DSC03469.JPG  DSC04502.JPG  DSC04906.JPG  DSC08172.JPG  DSC08561.JPG  DSC08961.JPG  DSC09393.JPG  DSC09757.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-12.JPG
DSC04070.JPG  DSC04503.JPG  DSC04907.JPG  DSC08173.JPG  DSC08562.JPG  DSC08962.JPG  DSC09394.JPG  DSC09758.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-13.JPG
DSC04071.JPG  DSC04504.JPG  DSC04908.JPG  DSC08175.JPG  DSC08563.JPG  DSC08963.JPG  DSC09395.JPG  DSC09759.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-14.JPG
DSC04072.JPG  DSC04505.JPG  DSC04909.JPG  DSC08176.JPG  DSC08564.JPG  DSC08964.JPG  DSC09396.JPG  DSC09760.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-15.JPG
DSC04073.JPG  DSC04506.JPG  DSC04910.JPG  DSC08177.JPG  DSC08565.JPG  DSC08965.JPG  DSC09397.JPG  DSC09761.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-16.JPG
DSC04074.JPG  DSC04507.JPG  DSC04911.JPG  DSC08178.JPG  DSC08566.JPG  DSC08966.JPG  DSC09398.JPG  DSC09762.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-17.JPG
DSC04075.JPG  DSC04508.JPG  DSC04912.JPG  DSC08179.JPG  DSC08567.JPG  DSC08967.JPG  DSC09399.JPG  DSC09763.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-18.JPG
DSC04076.JPG  DSC04509.JPG  DSC04913.JPG  DSC08180.JPG  DSC08568.JPG  DSC08968.JPG  DSC09400.JPG  DSC09764.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-19.JPG
DSC04078.JPG  DSC04510.JPG  DSC04915.JPG  DSC08181.JPG  DSC08569.JPG  DSC08969.JPG  DSC09401.JPG  DSC09765.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-1.JPG
DSC04079.JPG  DSC04511.JPG  DSC04916.JPG  DSC08182.JPG  DSC08570.JPG  DSC08970.JPG  DSC09402.JPG  DSC09766.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-20.JPG
DSC04080.JPG  DSC04512.JPG  DSC04917.JPG  DSC08183.JPG  DSC08571.JPG  DSC08971.JPG  DSC09403.JPG  DSC09767.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-21.JPG
DSC04081.JPG  DSC04513.JPG  DSC04918.JPG  DSC08184.JPG  DSC08572.JPG  DSC08972.JPG  DSC09404.JPG  DSC09768.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-22.JPG
DSC04082.JPG  DSC04514.JPG  DSC04919.JPG  DSC08185.JPG  DSC08573.JPG  DSC08973.JPG  DSC09405.JPG  DSC09769.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-23.JPG
DSC04083.JPG  DSC04515.JPG  DSC04920.JPG  DSC08186.JPG  DSC08574.JPG  DSC08974.JPG  DSC09406.JPG  DSC09771.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-2.JPG
DSC04084.JPG  DSC04516.JPG  DSC04921.JPG  DSC08187.JPG  DSC08575.JPG  DSC08975.JPG  DSC09407.JPG  DSC09772.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-3.JPG
DSC04085.JPG  DSC04517.JPG  DSC04922.JPG  DSC08188.JPG  DSC08576.JPG  DSC08976.JPG  DSC09408.JPG  DSC09773.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-4.JPG
DSC04086.JPG  DSC04518.JPG  DSC04923.JPG  DSC08189.JPG  DSC08577.JPG  DSC08977.JPG  DSC09409.JPG  DSC09774.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-5.JPG
DSC04087.JPG  DSC04519.JPG  DSC04924.JPG  DSC08190.JPG  DSC08578.JPG  DSC08978.JPG  DSC09410.JPG  DSC09775.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-6.JPG
DSC04088.JPG  DSC04520.JPG  DSC04925.JPG  DSC08191.JPG  DSC08579.JPG  DSC08979.JPG  DSC09411.JPG  DSC09776.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-7.JPG
DSC04089.JPG  DSC04521.JPG  DSC04926.JPG  DSC08192.JPG  DSC08580.JPG  DSC08980.JPG  DSC09412.JPG  DSC09777.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-8.JPG
DSC04090.JPG  DSC04522.JPG  DSC04928.JPG  DSC08193.JPG  DSC08581.JPG  DSC08981.JPG  DSC09413.JPG  DSC09778.JPG  Spinne-in-Plastiktüte-9.JPG
DSC04091.JPG  DSC04523.JPG  DSC04929.JPG  DSC08194.JPG  DSC08582.JPG  DSC08982.JPG  DSC09414.JPG  DSC09779.JPG  Süßkirschen-1.JPG
DSC04092.JPG  DSC04524.JPG  DSC04930.JPG  DSC08195.JPG  DSC08583.JPG  DSC08983.JPG  DSC09415.JPG  DSC09780.JPG  Süßkirschen-2.JPG
DSC04094.JPG  DSC04525.JPG  DSC04931.JPG  DSC08196.JPG  DSC08584.JPG  DSC08984.JPG  DSC09416.JPG  DSC09781.JPG  Süßkirschen-Blitz.JPG
DSC04095.JPG  DSC04526.JPG  DSC04932.JPG  DSC08197.JPG  DSC08585.JPG  DSC08985.JPG  DSC09417.JPG  DSC09782.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-1.JPG
DSC04096.JPG  DSC04527.JPG  DSC04933.JPG  DSC08198.JPG  DSC08586.JPG  DSC08986.JPG  DSC09418.JPG  DSC09783.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-2.JPG
DSC04098.JPG  DSC04528.JPG  DSC04934.JPG  DSC08199.JPG  DSC08587.JPG  DSC08987.JPG  DSC09419.JPG  DSC09784.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-3.JPG
DSC04099.JPG  DSC04529.JPG  DSC04935.JPG  DSC08203.JPG  DSC08588.JPG  DSC08988.JPG  DSC09420.JPG  DSC09785.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-4.JPG
DSC04100.JPG  DSC04534.JPG  DSC04936.JPG  DSC08204.JPG  DSC08589.JPG  DSC08989.JPG  DSC09421.JPG  DSC09786.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-5.JPG
DSC04101.JPG  DSC04535.JPG  DSC04937.JPG  DSC08205.JPG  DSC08590.JPG  DSC08990.JPG  DSC09422.JPG  DSC09787.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-6.JPG
DSC04103.JPG  DSC04536.JPG  DSC04939.JPG  DSC08206.JPG  DSC08591.JPG  DSC08991.JPG  DSC09423.JPG  DSC09788.JPG  Weiße-Motte--im-Gras-7.JPG
DSC04104.JPG  DSC04537.JPG  DSC04940.JPG  DSC08207.JPG  DSC08592.JPG  DSC08992.JPG  DSC09424.JPG  DSC09789.JPG
DSC04105.JPG  DSC04538.JPG  DSC04941.JPG  DSC08208.JPG  DSC08593.JPG  DSC08993.JPG  DSC09425.JPG  DSC09790.JPG
```

Comment: @mook765 please look again in the 2nd line of my post - the erroring command `mv "DSC00001.JPG" "12.10.2021-16:20:56.jpg"` is present there.

Comment: Are you running Debian? Looks like it might be the same issue as here: https://superuser.com/q/1409618

Comment: @Kyle well, I don't know what Debian in this case means, but as the behaviour is exactly the same (`/media/frederic/TOSHIBA EXT` is an NTFS drive !!!), I assume I am affected by this bug.

Comment: @Kyle my installed version is `8.30-3ubuntu2`, so it looks like I'm affected indeed, But how can I install an older version ? Also, why am I getting such bugs in an LTS ? I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.